# Why Perl can match two places with '/$/g'?

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote a sample code like this:

```
$var="123\n123\n\n\n\n\n1\n";
$var=~s/$/___/g;
print $var;
```

it output this:

```
123
123




1___
___
```

Why '/$/g' can match two places? I think it matched one is the last "\n" and the other is end of string. But I think it should only match the last line.

Comment: You have the g modifier. Which is global match. So you get the second entry because after all it is the start of a line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful of zero width regular expressions.   They often will not behave entirely the way that you expect.

In this case, the `$` boundary can actually match both directly before the last newline and directly after.  This is part of the spec of the `$`.

Therefore, your fix is to use the string end code `\z` instead of `$`:

```
$var = "abc\n";
$var =~ s/\z/<foo>/g;
print "'$var'";
```

Outputs:

```
'abc
<foo>'
```

Comment: I have understood what `$` mean exactly. It act as what you say. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`g` is a global modifier, that's why you're seeing replacement in all the places that `$` would match. If you don't use `g` then only first match will be replaced. So without g output will be:

```
123
123




1___
```

Also see: [$ and Perl's global regular expression modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940938/and-perls-global-regex-modifier)